# Secure Video Streaming - Limit by IP or device

Tags: opencv, security, video, raspberry-pi, streaming

As part of a student project, I am currently setting up device to device video streaming.

I am using two Raspberry Pi 3 with the camera modules and am adding face tracking via OpenCV (all in Python3).

**I want to** stream live Video captured by Raspberry Pi (X) to Raspberry Pi (Y) and vice versa. The Raspberries will not be in the same building/network.

**What I don't want**, is anyone being able to stream the video on a different device.

As I am new to the whole streaming and security idea, I was wondering if there is some way of adding security to live streams by limiting access by the device.
Say, the video of Raspberry Pi (X) **CAN ONLY** be viewed by Raspberry Pi (Y).

Is this possible? If not, what's the next most secure option (limiting by IP maybe).

I am also not fixed to using Raspberries for this project, if there is a different solution I'd love to hear about it.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: that's a general networking/security question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not the first person to do something like this. 
A raspberry pi is an excellent choice for the project and you should be able to find plenty of guides online to doing something like this.
You'll want to ensure you enable a strong username and password within whatever library you use.
If you want to protect the live stream with a username and password, you should enable this:
stream_auth_method 2
stream_authentication SOMEUSERNAME:SOMEPASSWORD 
https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera/

Comment: Hey, thanks reply!
I was also looking in the direction of surveillance projects but wondered if there was a layer I could add, next to authentication.
I tried googling for something like "Allow camera stream to be only accessed by one device simultaneously" and maybe add some sort of notification that would be sent to a admin address if a stream was accessed by more than one Ip's at the same time. 

Or maybe even go the step of saying that only device X with the right MAC address can open the stream.
I know MAC addresses can easily be spoofed but it would be a further layer. 
Any ideas?